# Remove of defer plugin related stylesheets

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a site running with `WooCommerce` and `WPBakery`.

I'm trying to reduce unused CSS requests as highlighted by `Page Speed Insights`.

Currently, here are the CSS files that are being generated by the two plugins:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" id="wc-blocks-vendors-style-css" href="http://theme.test/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/build/wc-blocks-vendors-style.css?ver=1629402699" type="text/css" media="all">

<link rel="stylesheet" id="wc-blocks-style-css" href="http://theme.test/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/build/wc-blocks-style.css?ver=1629402699" type="text/css" media="all">

<link rel="stylesheet" id="js_composer_front-css" href="http://theme.test/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css?ver=6.7.0" type="text/css" media="all">
```

I'm looking to either:

1. De-register those stylesheets (as I have tried below).
2. `defer` all three of these stylesheets

I have tried the following below:

```html
function remove_plugin_styles() {
  wp_deregister_style( 'wc-blocks-style' );  // woocommerce
  wp_deregister_style( 'wc-blocks-vendors-style-css' ); // woocommerce
  wp_deregister_style( 'js_composer_front-css' ); // js composer (wpbakery)
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_plugin_styles', 100 );
```

With the above `wc-blocks-style` and `wc-blocks-vendors-style-css` are successfully removed. But, `js_composer_front-css` is still loaded in.

Is there a way to either `defer` all these sheet (and any other plugin related css files), or remove them?

Answer (score 0):

`defer` (and `async`, for that matter) are specifically for [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tags and don't apply to [`<link> stylesheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), and thus you can't really defer them in the traditional sense.

That said, your issue is that you're trying to deregister the wrong handle. The `-css` is automatically appended to enqueued CSS files by WordPress itself.

Changing the last deregister to:

```
wp_deregister_style( 'js_composer_front' ); // js composer (wpbakery)
```

Will properly deregister it